# Kafka connect JDBC sink - Mapping nested json to mulitple rows

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

As part of requirement, we are going ahead with Kafka connect to push data to our database. What I read so far is that there will be a 1x1 mapping between message and db row i.e. for a single message on Kafka, there will be a corresponding entry in database.
I wanted to know if there is a possibility of breaking down a nested json into multiple rows to be inserted in to db?

The 2 possibilities that I can think of are:-
1) Write custom connector for jdbc sink
2) Use consumer group instead of kafka connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use consumer group instead of kafka connect

Connect *is* a consumer group. It's highly recommended not to write your own logic for handling connection failures, offset management, retires, etc. and let Connect do that work for you. If those "benefits" don't work for you, even then I think it would be better to fork the Connector code  (your option 2) rather than write a plain Consumer

Connect single message transforms are roughly what you're looking for. Otherwise, you would write a consumer/producer/Kstreams application to read and write back to a "flattened" topic, and then Connect reads that output topic into the database.

Note: JDBC isn't your only option. Mongodb or Couchbase handle nested JSON just fine

Comment: Thanks. We can't replace RDBMS with NoSQL db for now. It seems forking the JDBCSink connector would be a plausible option for now.

Comment: Up to you. I personally would go with Kafka Streams and use `flatMap` operator

Comment: Will also look into Kafka streams and review the use case again. Thanks for the suggestion.